# Handle not found when searching string in slice

Tags: go

Based on this fairly simple code based on the [sort package](https://golang.org/src/sort/search.go). The response index of `o1` is invalid as pointed by @JimB because a bigger or equals operator is required for binary search

```
l := []string{"o1", "o2", "o3"} 

i1 := sort.Search(len(l), func(i int) bool { return strings.EqualFold(l[i], "o1") })
fmt.Println("o1:", i1) //PRINTS 3 - WRONG
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nUs-ozTYsY

The working solution is:

```
l := []string{"o1", "o2", "o3"} 

i1 := sort.Search(len(l), func(i int) bool { return l[i] >= "o1" })
fmt.Println("o1:", i1)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/WRsijy_xzV

However this still it's important to bare in mind a important last check. `The return value is the index to insert x`, which means that you can end up with something like:

```
o1: 0 (index 0)
o2: 1
o3: 2
o777: 0 (Same 0 index!)
```

Therefore it's important as pointed by @JimB to check for `data[i] == 23` separately.

```
if i < len(data) && ---> data[i] == x <--- {
    x is present at data[i]
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: from the search docs `Search uses binary search to find and return the smallest index i in [0, n) at which f(i) is true`. If you want to test if the item is in the list, you must check that separately. From the example in the same documentation section: `If the caller wants to find whether 23 is in the slice, it must test data[i] == 23 separately`

Comment: Awesome! This explain `data[i] == x` at the end of the if check. Great stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A binary search requires a greater than or less than comparison, otherwise it would just be a linear search over the slice. Any comparison greater than the value at the requested index needs to be true, in order for the search method to scan backwards looking for the smallest index.

See the default implementation of the string search function from the sort package:

https://golang.org/src/sort/search.go?s=3673:3717#L91

```
func SearchStrings(a []string, x string) int {
    return Search(len(a), func(i int) bool { return a[i] >= x })
}
```